# Master Page does not exist error in an irrelevant directory

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, file-not-found

I have a ridiculous question about master pages in asp.net.
I have several pages under a project and all of their master page paths are determined like this:

```
    MasterPageFile="~/zFrame/InterfaceMaster.master"
```

However when I run the project, I see the page giving following error:

```
    The file '/interface/Intertech.Interface.InvoicePayments/zFrame/InterfaceMaster.master' does not exist.
```

Normally the master page must be in the "zFrame" directory. the second directory does not contain master page.

The whole site used to run perfectly until a few days ago. and only some of the pages come up with this error

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the two paths?  What "~/" means compared to just "/"?  They actually point to the same folder, one is just relevant to the application, and the other to the website as a whole.  The second is what the first maps to using IIS settings based on an IIS application.  So if something in IIS changed the root of the application, then the "~/somepath" would map out to a different full server-relative path.

Comment: Yes, I see the difference of the two symbols for the path.You mean, the problem is root of the applications is changed, right? However we do not have local IIS configurations and deployments, our file system is run by a remote IIS setup (where I cannot access).

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to convert Intertech.Interface.InvoicePayments to a web application in IIS Manager

Comment: Ah this is where I got stuck. Firstly we run the project on file system, and the url shows a remote server where our computer name is given by a url parameter(I know this sounds complicated but we do not have IIS sonfigurations locally). Secondly under the same directory(Intertech.Interface.InvoicePayments) some of the pages run with master page without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

As an advancement, I could access the IIS. There are other projects listed as different folders under the "Default Web Site". All are working fine except the project "InvoicePayments". I would love to convert it to application, but others are not converted to applications and still working fine. I'm totally confused.